# startxwin - startx on cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, x11

I recently installed cygwin, and as I would like to use matplotilb to show plots I tried to make x11 work. However, after installing the packages from the setup, I haven't been able to start a new terminal:

- opening a server from the windows - all app - cygwin-x opens a new window for a fraction of a second
- startxwin from cygwin shell causes this output, not opening any window

  > `$ startxwin`
  >
  > Welcome to the XWin X Server
  >   Vendor: The Cygwin/X Project
  >   Release: 1.19.5.0
  >   OS: CYGWIN_NT-10.0 DESKTOP-4MNGT8H 2.9.0(0.318/5/3) 2017-09-12 10:18 x86_64
  >   OS: Windows 10  [Windows NT 10.0 build 15063] (Win64)
  >   Package: version 1.19.5-1 built 2017-11-03
  >
  > XWin was started with the following command line:
  >
  > /usr/bin/XWin :0 -multiwindow -auth /home/voyo/.serverauth.5460
  >
  > (II) xorg.conf is not supported
  >   (II) See http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html for more information
  >   LoadPreferences: /home/voyo/.XWinrc not found
  >   LoadPreferences: Loading /etc/X11/system.XWinrc
  >   LoadPreferences: Done parsing the configuration file...
  >   winDetectSupportedEngines - RemoteSession: no
  >   winDetectSupportedEngines - DirectDraw4 installed, allowing ShadowDDNL
  >   winDetectSupportedEngines - Returning, supported engines 00000005
  >   winSetEngine - Multi Window or Rootless => ShadowGDI
  >   winScreenInit - Using Windows display depth of 32 bits per pixel
  >   winAllocateFBShadowGDI - Creating DIB with width: 1920 height: 1080 depth: 32
  >   winFinishScreenInitFB - Masks: 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff
  >   winInitVisualsShadowGDI - Masks 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff BPRGB 8 d 24 bpp 32
  >   MIT-SHM extension disabled due to lack of kernel support
  >   XFree86-Bigfont extension local-client optimization disabled due to lack of >shared memory support in the kernel
  >   glWinSelectGLimplementation: Loaded 'cygnativeGLthunk.dll'
  >   (II) AIGLX: Testing pixelFormatIndex 1
  >   GL_VERSION:     4.4.0 - Build 20.19.15.4444
  >   GL_VENDOR:      Intel
  >   GL_RENDERER:    Intel(R) HD Graphics 400
  >   (II) GLX: enabled GLX_SGI_make_current_read
  >   (II) GLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control
  >   (II) GLX: enabled GLX_MESA_swap_control
  >   (II) GLX: enabled GLX_SGIX_pbuffer
  >   (II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_multisample
  >   (II) GLX: enabled GLX_SGIS_multisample
  >   (II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float
  >   (II) GLX: enabled GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float
  >   (II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context
  >   (II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_profile
  >   (II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness
  >   (II) GLX: enabled GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile
  >   (II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB
  >   (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
  >   (II) 92 pixel formats reported by wglGetPixelFormatAttribivARB
  >   (II) 56 fbConfigs
  >   (II) ignored pixel formats: 0 not OpenGL, 0 unknown pixel type, 36 unaccelerated
  >   (II) GLX: Initialized Win32 native WGL GL provider for screen 0
  >   winPointerWarpCursor - Discarding first warp: 960 540
  >   (--) 5 mouse buttons found
  >   (--) Setting autorepeat to delay=500, rate=31
  >   (--) Windows keyboard layout: "00020409" (00020409) "United >States->International", type 4
  >   (--) Found matching XKB configuration "English (USA,International)"
  >   (--) Model = "pc105" Layout = "us_intl" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
  >   Rules = "base" Model = "pc105" Layout = "us_intl" Variant = "none" Options = >"none"
  >   winInitMultiWindowWM - DISPLAY=:0.0
  >   winMultiWindowXMsgProc - DISPLAY=:0.0
  >   winInitMultiWindowWM - xcb_connect () returned and successfully opened the >display.
  >   winClipboardThreadProc - DISPLAY=:0.0
  >   winProcEstablishConnection - winInitClipboard returned.
  >   winMultiWindowXMsgProc - xcb_connect() returned and successfully opened the >display.
  >   OS maintains clipboard viewer chain: yes
  >   winClipboardProc - XOpenDisplay () returned and successfully opened the display.
  >   Using Composite redirection
- startx causes a similar output, a new blank terminal appears for a moment and then closes immediately, the output is this.

  > `$ startx`
  >
  > Welcome to the XWin X Server
  >   Vendor: The Cygwin/X Project
  >   Release: 1.19.5.0
  >   OS: CYGWIN_NT-10.0 DESKTOP-4MNGT8H 2.9.0(0.318/5/3) 2017-09-12 10:18 x86_64
  >   OS: Windows 10  [Windows NT 10.0 build 15063] (Win64)
  >   Package: version 1.19.5-1 built 2017-11-03
  >
  > XWin was started with the following command line:
  >
  > /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /home/voyo/.serverauth.6320
  >
  > (II) xorg.conf is not supported
  >   (II) See http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html for more information
  >   LoadPreferences: /home/voyo/.XWinrc not found
  >   LoadPreferences: Loading /etc/X11/system.XWinrc
  >   LoadPreferences: Done parsing the configuration file...
  >   winDetectSupportedEngines - RemoteSession: no
  >   winDetectSupportedEngines - DirectDraw4 installed, allowing ShadowDDNL
  >   winDetectSupportedEngines - Returning, supported engines 00000005
  >   winSetEngine - Using Shadow DirectDraw NonLocking
  >   winScreenInit - Using Windows display depth of 32 bits per pixel
  >   winWindowProc - WM_SIZE - new client area w: 1902 h: 983
  >   winFinishScreenInitFB - Masks: 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff
  >   MIT-SHM extension disabled due to lack of kernel support
  >   XFree86-Bigfont extension local-client optimization disabled due to lack of >shared memory support in the kernel
  >   (EE) AIGLX: No native OpenGL in modes with a root window
  >   (II) IGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
  >   (II) IGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
  >   (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
  >   winPointerWarpCursor - Discarding first warp: 951 491
  >   (--) 5 mouse buttons found
  >   (--) Setting autorepeat to delay=500, rate=31
  >   (--) Windows keyboard layout: "00020409" (00020409) "United >States->International", type 4
  >   (--) Found matching XKB configuration "English (USA,International)"
  >   (--) Model = "pc105" Layout = "us_intl" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
  >   Rules = "base" Model = "pc105" Layout = "us_intl" Variant = "none" Options = >"none"
  >   winClipboardThreadProc - DISPLAY=:0.0
  >   OS maintains clipboard viewer chain: yes
  >   winProcEstablishConnection - winInitClipboard returned.
  >   winClipboardProc - XOpenDisplay () returned and successfully opened the display.
  >   xinit: connection to X server lost
  >
  > waiting for X server to shut down winClipboardProc - >winClipboardFlushWindowsMessageQueue trapped WM_QUIT message, exiting main loop.
  >   winClipboardProc - XDestroyWindow succeeded.
  >   winDeinitMultiWindowWM - Noting shutdown in progress
  >   (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

  - following another answer I tried this command:
    `$ xinit -- -multiwindow -clipboard &`

which opens a new terminal, but white and with very little characters and very difficult to manage.

Any idea on how to make it properly work?

Comment: This should be moved to superuser.com, I guess. Not a programming question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following starts X for me:

`startxwin -- -listen tcp &`

Note that this starts the X server only, it does not start any X applications.  Start applications manually, e.g., `xterm &` (or create shortcuts to them).

To avoid having a white xterm with small characters, put resources in ~/.Xresources.  For example, I have the following in my ~/.Xresources:

```
XTerm*FaceName: DejaVu Sans Mono
XTerm*FaceSize: 12
XTerm*Geometry: 80x30
XTerm*Foreground: lightgrey
XTerm*Background: #201810
```